# Python doesn't call fucntion

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

It's a very strange problem. Python 3.7.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def iter_elements_by_name_please(handle, name):
    print('It works')
    events = ET.iterparse(handle, events=("start", "end",))
    _, root = next(events)  # Grab the root element.
    for event, elem in events:
        if event == "end" and elem.tag == name:
            yield elem
            root.clear()  # Free up memory by clearing the root element.


iter_elements_by_name_please('test.xml', 'gabm')
```

Such code just returns 0, in debugger i can see, that it doesn't go into function. If i removes `for` cycle, it starts working as excpected. Tryed on 2 differnet machines on differnt os.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fact you use `yield` means that `iter_elements_by_name_please` is a function that returns a `generator` (like `range` does).

you can read more at the [official wiki page for Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

you need to iterate it to get the elements.

try:

```py
for elem in iter_elements_by_name_please('test.xml', 'gabm'):
    print(elem)
```